# Is there a way in python to use a subclass attribute generated by __init_subclass__ as a type hint

Tags: python, subclass, type-hinting, metaclass, python-typing

How can I type hint in a base class to a type which is an attribute of the subclass. For example the type hint (obviously wrong) on `IFoo.foo` below:

```
class IFoo(ABC):

    def __init_subclass__(cls, a_type: AMeta, **kwargs):
        cls.a_type = a_type
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)

    def foo(self, a: self.a_type):
        a.thing()
```

possibly the best solution is to use a `Generic` like

```
AT = TypeVar['AT']

class IFoo(Generic[AT],ABC):

    def __init_subclass__(cls, a_type: AMeta, **kwargs):
        cls.a_type = a_type
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)

    def foo(self, a: AT):
        a.thing()

class ConcreteFoo(IFoo[at], a_type=at):
    pass
```

But is anyone has a better idea I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Assuming this is possible, what exactly do you suppose it would accomplish? Type hints are meaningless at runtime, and static analysis code wouldn't catch this type of at-runtime behavior. The best way to actually annotate `foo()` would probably be with a `Union` of all possible values of `AMeta`

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy thanks. Yes I understand tat, it's basically the question I'm asking. The `Union` idea is fine but it actually makes it pretty hard to write useful code without creating circular imports. I think the best I can do may be to use a `Generic`. I've edited the question to show what I mean

Comment: I don't think there's a better solution than what you've already thought of.